# Dynamic UISlider - Image is not showing

Tags: ios, uislider

I have created a UISlider with images dynamically using the below code and but the resultant UI is showing only the default UISlider. Please anyone tell me, why the images are not showing on the slider. (UISlider is loaded on a UIView class which also created dynamically)

```
self.slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width * 80.0/100.0, frame.size.height)];
self.slider.minimumValue = minValue;
self.slider.maximumValue = maxValue;
self.slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_tab.png"]
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_tab.png"]
                  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.slider.continuous = NO;
[self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(SliderChanged:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self addSubview:self.slider];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: once check your IBOutlet connection.

Comment: Still not found the solution... I checked the image name and it is correct

Comment: Are you taken slider in Xib or not?

Comment: It is created programmatically inside the a UIView

Comment: Just create the sample project and paste the same code .

Answer (score 1):

I have executed your code it it working fine . I think the issue is with your images . Please check your image names (Those are Case Sensitive) .i.e .jpg or .png

Comment: Still not found the solution. I suspect the problem happening because the parent View I created using program and the IB may not be properly connected. Can any one shed some light on this?

Comment: Where do you have all those images? i.e in your project folder or where?

Comment: Try two different images for minimum and maximum track images

Comment: Images are inside project folder only. Another thing I noticed is, minimum/maximumTrackTintColor function also has no effect. maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0f green:1/255.0f blue:1/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

Comment: Are you creating any other sliders programmatically or do you have any other UISliders in the xib ?

Comment: slider is created dynamically inside the UIView derived class, And again, this UIView is created dynamically inside another UIView. Can this hierarchy cause any issue?

Comment: ... no other slider is created in the Xib. But one more similar UISlider is there in the another UIView

Comment: Try to do like this just comment the other slider code so that you can know the issue? or try to use other imagenames for maximum or minimum images

Answer (score 0):

set minimumTrackTintColor property color as default.
set maximumTrackTintColor property color as default.

it is working for me.